# Nativescript libraries too big for Android

Tags: android, nativescript, apk

I understand that for Android build, apk includes different runtimes for four different architectures.  I read that those are supposed to be ~4MB each, making apk 12MB right out of the box.

However looking at apk as a zip, mine are 11-12 MB each, meaning my apk is 45MB.  Our last version was 12MB (our app is pretty simple - webview and one page showing pdfs).

The only change was i added utilities module, updated nativescript version and ran npm update - which updated some packages.

Here is my package.json (abcxyz used in spots here for privacy).

Any help greatly appreciated:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "abcxyz",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.2"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.3"
    }
  },
  "description": "abcxyz",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.0",
    "@nota/nativescript-webview-ext": "^6.5.4",
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^3.4.2",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^2.4.3",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.5.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "gitHead": "abycxyz",
  "readme": "abcxyz"
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I'm wondering why my nativescript library files are 11-12 MB each instead of 4 MB each.